# How do you shutdown a ZMQ QueueDevice from a worker thread in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, zeromq, netmq

First time using ZMQ and I'm trying to setup a process to handle many getimage requests. What happens when I'm debugging is several exceptions that I'm trying to fix and implement a way to stop the QueueDevice terminate all the thread and exit gracefully.

1. receiver.Connect(BackendBindAddress); throws An unhandled exception of type 'NetMQ.InvalidException' occurred in NetMQ.dll with the error code NetMQ.zmq.ErrorCode.EINVAL. Why doesn't this exception stop further execution of the thread?
2. I've tried making QueueDevice a static field and using queueDevice.stop() in the shutdown message function but then the threads start throwing TerminatingExceptions and neverexit. So can I shut down all the threads and the main thread?

Test driving the code

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void ProgramStartupShutdownTest()
    {
        var mockClientWrapper = new Mock<IClient>(MockBehavior.Strict);

        var target = new SocketListener(2, mockClientWrapper.Object);

        var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => target.StartListening("tcp://localhost:81"));
        using (var client = NetMQContext.Create())
        {
           var socket = client.CreateRequestSocket();
           socket.Connect("tcp://localhost:81");
           var m = new NetMQMessage(new ShutdownMessage().CreateMessageFrames());
           socket.SendMessage(m);
        }

        var timedout = task.Wait(200);
        Assert.IsTrue(timedout);
    }
```

Code I'm working with

```
private const string BackendBindAddress = "inproc://workers";
public SocketListener(int numberOfWorkers, IClient client )
    {
        numberOfThreads = numberOfWorkers;
        _client = client;
    }

public void StartListening(string address)
    {
        StartZeroMQ(address, context =>
        {
            for (var i = 0; i <= numberOfThreads; i++)
            {
                var t = new Thread(WorkerRoutine);
                t.Start(
                        new WorkerParamters
                        {
                            Context = context,
                            Client = _client
                        }
                    );
            }
        });
    }


    private void StartZeroMQ(string address, Action<NetMQContext> setupWorkers)
    {
        using (var context = NetMQContext.Create())
        {
            var queueDevice = new QueueDevice(context, address, BackendBindAddress, DeviceMode.Blocking);
            setupWorkers(context);
            queueDevice.Start();
        }
    }

    struct WorkerParamters
    {
        public NetMQContext Context;
        public IClient Client;
    }

    private static void WorkerRoutine(object startparameter)
    {
            var wp = (WorkerParamters) startparameter;
            var client = wp.Client;
            using (var receiver = wp.Context.CreateResponseSocket())
            {
                receiver.Connect(BackendBindAddress);
                var running = true;
                while (running)
                {
                        var message = receiver.ReceiveMessage();
                        var letter = Message.ParseMessageFrame(message,
                                                               imageMessage => GetImage(imageMessage, client),
                                                               videoMessage => GetVideo(videoMessage, client),
                                                               shutdownMessage =>
                                                               {
                                                                   running = false;
                                                                   return true;
                                                               });

                        receiver.Send(letter.ToJson(), Encoding.Unicode);
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: Got half my answer, the inproc protocol requires the socket to be bound before you connect to it. https://github.com/zeromq/netmq/issues/165

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To overcome the issue I added an Initialize method to the device, call it before starting the workers and after calling the workers start the device.

You can grab the code from [here](https://github.com/somdoron/netmq/tree/DeviceBaseInitialize)(you need to compile the project from the repository), I will add a pull request later.

You can also write the device logic by hand, it shouldn't be complicated.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking into writing it but passed on having to maintain it later in a few months, when my zmq knowledge gets rustier. Namely I didn't want to also learn how to use the poller on top of what I've already learned.